# Error - "Objects of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame not supported by autoplot."

Tags: r, package, time-series

Trying my hands on `autoplot` and `ggseasonplot` functions, but neither working. Please guide / help.

```
library(readxl)
new<-read_excel('NEW DATA.xlsx')
View(new)
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(new)
class(new)
ggseasonplot(new)
```

Error: Objects of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame not supported by autoplot.

Comment: Add an explanation what you expect, what data you used, and so on

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, time series does not support data.frame and has to be converted into time series format. The reason this happens, as you can not tell R to convert the whole table / matrix / data frame to plot, without giving it the constraints, telling what to plot, and how to plot.

I used

```
my1 <- ts (name of the data frame, [,2], start = year, 
           month, date, frequency = in my case it was 31)
```

As I only wanted to plot my column 2, I wrote [,2].

```
my1 <- ts (data1, [,2], start = 1981,1,1, frequency = 31)
```

This converted it to time series, which I plotted later by commands-

1. `Autoplot (my1)`
2. `ggseasonplot (my1)`.